# Will standard M5 T-slot nuts fit these different 2020 aluminium extrusions?

Tags: aluminum, fasteners

I am trying to source the parts for a [Wilson II 3D printer](http://reprap.org/wiki/Category:Wilson_II), and the recommended struts are made from 2020 aluminium extrusions, like so:

[image: 2020 Aluminium extrusion]

However, in Bangkok, I can only find this type:

[image: 2020 Aluminium extrusion in Bangkok]

Note that the profile/shape of the slot is markedly different from the image above.

Whilst looking about on the web, I have also found other types, like these:

[image: Various types of 2020 Aluminium extrusion]

Again, the profile of the slot varies considerably.

My question is whether standard full size

[image: Full T-nut]

and half size T nuts

[image: Half T-nut]

will still fit all of these different types? Or are there different T-nuts for the different types of extruded 2020 aluminium, depending on the profile/shape of the slot.

Also, why are there the different designs, does each type have an advantage for particular applications (with respect to strength, weight, etc.)?

---

#### Update

For completeness and accuracy, the 2020 extrusion, that I obtained in Bangkok, actually has this profile:

[image: 2020 Aluminium Extrusion BKK#1]

and here is a more in-focus photo, of four, in a 2 x 2 configuration:

[image: 2020 Aluminium Extrusion BKK#2]

As ericnutsch states, in his answer, only regular hexagonal M5 nuts will fit.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't think that any profile has any major advantage over any other. I use [openbuilds v-slot](http://openbuildspartstore.com/v-slot-linear-rail/) on a lot of my projects (its 2020 designed for perpendicular v rollers) and all the [aliexpress t-nut hardware](https://www.aliexpress.com/item/100pcs-lot-M5-Nickel-Plated-Carbon-Steel-Hammer-Nut-Aluminum-Connector-T-Fastener-Sliding-Nut-For/32317449512.html) I have bought works fine.

Worst case, you can use regular nuts with the aluminum rail you have access to; they are not as convenient but will work fine.